# Adding titles to file data while moving position based on pattern matches (SED or AWK) while preserving counts

Tags: awk, sed, formatting, counting

I am currently struggling with a query in which i need to take data from a file with 2 or more columns and not only extract the data, but add a header to each column based on the data given. Here's a sample of the file data.

--

```
test_AA.98
test_AA.99+
8 35=Apples
16 35=Pears

test_AA.100
14 35=Apples
12 35=Pears
test_AB.101-
15 35=Banannas
```

-- If i cat and awk the first column - cat testfile | awk '{ print $1 }' - results in

```
test_AA.98
test_AA.99+
8
16


test_AA.100
14
12

test_AB.101-
15
```

-- If i cat and wak the second column - cat testfile | awk '{ print $2 }' - results in

```
35=Apples
35=Pears



35=Apples
35=Oranges


35=Banannas
```

-- Can anyone offer a solution to where I can add a header title to my data based on pattern match (test*) to $1 position, match 35=*, move to $2 position, while keeping the count and values in place? My desired outcome.

```
Suppliers,  Red=35=Apples, Green=35=Pears, Yellow=35=Banannas
            
test_AA.98, 0,  0,  0
test_AA.99+,    8,  16, 0
test_AA.100,    14, 12, 0
test_AB.101-,   0,  0,  15
```

I've only found some solutions to add the headers, but haven't figured away to place the correct values under the headers.

```
sed '1iSuppliers, Red=35=Apples, Green=35=Pears, Yellow=35=Banannas' testfile
Suppliers, 35=Apples, 35=Pears, 35=Banannas
test_AA.98
test_AA.99+
8 35=Apples
16 35=Pears


test_AA.100
14 35=Apples
12 35=Oranges

test_AB.101-
15 35=Banannas
```

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Here's something to start you off.

With awk **script**:

```
# set column separator
# r[] - output columns
BEGIN { OFS=", "; r[0]="Suppliers" }

# first pass:

# find name from $2, store for later lookup
# t[] - test if $2 value already seen
# c[] - lookup table for column index by name
FNR==NR && NF==2 && !t[$2]++ { r[++n]=$2; c[$2]=n }
FNR==NR { next }

# second pass:

# line with single field ends previous block
NF==1 {
    # print row (or header if first line)
    s=r[0]; for(i=1;i<=n;i++) s = s OFS r[i]; print s

    # reset columns for subsequent lines
    r[0]=$1; for(i=1;i<=n;i++) r[i]=0

    next
}

# insert value into appropriate output column
NF==2 { r[c[$2]]=$1 }

# output the final line
END { s=r[0]; for(i=1;i<=n;i++) s = s OFS r[i]; print s }
```

Invoke as:

```
awk -f script testfile testfile
```

With your sample input, this produces:

```
Suppliers, 35=Apples, 35=Pears, 35=Banannas
test_AA.98, 0, 0, 0
test_AA.99+, 8, 16, 0
test_AA.100, 14, 12, 0
test_AB.101-, 0, 0, 15
```

If you already know all the values the headers can take, and you want to prefix them with something, or display them in a particular order, you can initialise `r[]` and `c[]` appropriately in BEGIN. Then delete the `FNR==NR ...` lines, and invoke as `awk -f script testfile`.

Comment: Hi Jhnc.. Their will be many suppliers and many various entries for 35=* depending on what happens during the day/night. But I really appreciate your reply and will test out your solution later.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    col2tag[++numCols] = "Suppliers"
    OFS = ",\t"
}
NF==1 {
    rowNr = ++numRows
    colNr = 1
}
NF==2 {
    if ( $2 in tag2col ) {
        colNr = tag2col[$2]
    }
    else {
        colNr = ++numCols
        col2tag[colNr] = $2
        tag2col[$2] = colNr
    }
}
NF {
    vals[rowNr,colNr] = $1
}
END {
    for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", col2tag[colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            val = ( (rowNr,colNr) in vals ? vals[rowNr,colNr] : 0 )
            printf "%s%s", val, (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Suppliers,      35=Apples,      35=Pears,       35=Banannas
test_AA.98,     0,      0,      0
test_AA.99+,    8,      16,     0
test_AA.100,    14,     12,     0
test_AB.101-,   0,      0,      15
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
Suppliers,     35=Apples,  35=Pears,  35=Banannas
test_AA.98,    0,          0,         0
test_AA.99+,   8,          16,        0
test_AA.100,   14,         12,        0
test_AB.101-,  0,          0,         15
```

Comment: Most appreciated!!